# How to understand 'the translation equivalents do contrast as present vs future tense.'?

Tags: meaning, word-usage

> Data like that shown in [3] does not by itself refute a future tense
> analysis: there are languages (such as French) where the translation
> equivalents do contrast **as** present **vs** future tense.

Does it mean 'the translation equivalents do contrast between present and future tense'?

There is a similar sentence:

> But it does place the onus of proof on defenders of the future tense
> analysis to demonstrate why will (and shall) should be differentiated
> from the others **as tense auxiliaries vs mood auxiliaries**.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looking at the snippets here I guess you are reading an academic linguistics paper about the "will" construction in English.  And this paper discusses different ways of analysing a sentence like "I will eat dinner."

One analysis is that "will eat" is a verb in the future tense, with a prefix "will" (which is written with a space)  so the bracketing is (I ((will eat) dinner)).  The other has "will" as a modal verb, completed by a subordinate clause "eat dinner".  Bracketing (I (will (eat dinner))).

The author notes that if you translate "I eat dinner" and "I will eat dinner" to French (Je dîne and Je dînerai) The sentences contrast in tense, providing evidence that "will eat" is actually a future tense. But why distinguish tense auxiliaries from other based only on the English syntax?

Comment: How to understand 'as' in the two sentences?

Comment: prepostion. used in "A presents as B"  meaning "like" or "similar to" or "in the manner of"